# request.method == "POST" not working in Update blog post view

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

While creating an Update Blog Post view/functionality I got this.
I don't know what's wrong my *post_update* view is working but the if condition (request.method=="POST") is not.

I am following this tutorial https://youtu.be/WYvUB_eCPTs?t=1287

***views.py***

```
def post_update(request, id):
    title = 'Update'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)
    author = get_author(request.user)
    print('After author')

    if request.method == "POST":
        print('I am not working')
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = author
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse("post-list", kwargs={
                'id': form.instance.id
            }))
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, "post_update.html", context)
```

***urls.py***

```
path('post/<id>/', post, name="post-detail"),
    path('post/<id>/update', post_update, name="post-update"),
    path('post/<id>/delete', post_delete, name="post-delete"),
    path('create/', post_create, name="post-create"),
```

***post_update.html***

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-8 offset-2 mb-5 mt-5">
    <h3>{{title}} an Article </h3>
    {{ form.media }}
    <form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form|crispy}}
        <button class= "btn btn-primary btn-lg w-50" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script src="{% static 'vendor/tiny.js' %}"> </script>

{% endblock content %}
```

***Console***

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
After author
[08/Nov/2020 10:05:20] "GET /post/1/update HTTP/1.1" 200 12520
Not Found: /post/1/css/content.css
[08/Nov/2020 10:05:23] "GET /post/1/css/content.css HTTP/1.1" 404 3148
[08/Nov/2020 10:05:27] "POST /post/1/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15770
```

Comment: The url for the post_update view is `post/<id>/update`.  The console does not show any calls to that url with a POST action.

Comment: Where is your content.css placed?

Comment: Instead of a function based view, try using a class based view.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview

Comment: add your base.html file

Comment: you didn't call update at all. due to console you are calling post function not post_update !